# Where do I put log files of scripts or executables ran as user?

Tags: fhs

What would be a good place to put log files for executables that run as local user?

I notice there are a bunch of system-like directories in my home folder, ~/.config has things that for a system-wide equivalent would be in /etc, ~/.local/share is the analogue to /usr(/local)?/share. So essentially I'm asking what the user equivalent of /var/log would be.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27965014/2072269, https://superuser.com/a/1449386/334516

Comment: thanks, so `~/.local/share/<appname>/something.log` I gather

Comment: Or, possibly even better, based on the linked pages: `${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}/app/app.log`

Comment: I use `$HOME/var/log`. I manage my user (me) with local versions (not copies) of many system directories.